# Generate table in pdf with prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, prawn

I have successfully generated pdf file using prawn pdf gem inside the controller , but I want to separate class files and call the method of the class to make the controller code look clean.
Here is my in-controller method

```
  def download_pdf
if Subscriber.count<50
  addSubscribers()
else
  @subscribers=Subscriber.all.order("name ASC")
end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf do
      pdf = Prawn::Document.new
      table_data = Array.new
      table_data << ["Name","E-mail","Phone"]
      @subscribers.each do |p|
        table_data << [p.name, p.email,p.phone]
      end
      pdf.table(table_data, :width => 500, :cell_style => { :inline_format => true })
      send_data pdf.render, filename: 'test.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline'
    end
  end
```

end

But when I try to use the following code->

```
def download_pdf
  @subscribers=Subscriber.all.order("name ASC")
  PdfCreator.new(@subscribers)
end
```

And the PdfCreator class is ->

```
    class PdfCreator

  def initialize(subscribers)
    @subs=subscr
    download_pdf()
  end

  def download_pdf()
      pdf = Prawn::Document.new
      table_data = Array.new
      table_data << ["Name","E-mail","Phone"]
      @subs.each do |p|
        table_data << [p.name, p.email,p.phone]
      end
      pdf.table(table_data, :width => 500, :cell_style => { :inline_format => true })
    send_data pdf.render, filename: 'test.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline'
  end

end
```

respond to is not resolving as a method. I found some codes on generating pdf from an outside class but only for normal texts not for tables- Any help regarding how to do it for tables , that will be a great help

Comment: What is your actual error? One thing I will note is that `send_data` is going to be an issue in that class and should be left in  the controller but "code is obviously errorenous" does not really help us solve any other issues you may be experiencing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`send_data` is a controller-level method, and won't work inside your custom class, and the `respond_to` might be needed for your route to respond appropriately.

Let's try keeping what's needed in the controller and extract only PDF-generating logic to the new `PdfCreator` class:

```
def download_pdf
  @subscribers=Subscriber.all.order("name ASC")

  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf do
      pdf = PdfCreator.new(@subscribers)
      send_data pdf.render, filename: 'test.pdf', type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline'
    end
  end
end


class PdfCreator
  def initialize(subscribers)
    @subs=subscribers
  end

  def render()
    pdf = Prawn::Document.new
    table_data = Array.new
    table_data << ["Name","E-mail","Phone"]
    @subs.each do |p|
      table_data << [p.name, p.email,p.phone]
    end
    pdf.table(table_data, :width => 500, :cell_style => { inline_format: true })
    pdf.render
  end
end
```

Comment: hi , I tried this code and it shows  *Failed to Load the pdf document*

Comment: @Achy97 Sorry about that. I just prototyped it locally, and realize I missed calling `pdf.render` inside of `PdfCreator#render`. I've edited it to fix that issue.

Comment: hi, @Unixmonkey I encountered a problem today which i didnt notice previously..the pdf is being generated successfully BUT THE problem is when the content is much more than one page- then only First page has table header but the following oages do not have table headers can you please help me overcome the problem?

Comment: @Achy97 I think you can pass `header: true` to the `table` options, and it will repeat like so: `pdf.table(table_data, width: 500, cell_style: { inline_format: true }, header: true)`